# How to add columns in a .csv using existing data in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

In the 'details' column, every entry has 'Mobile' and 'Email" text inside them. I want to separate out Mobile Number and Email-ID of corresponding entries in different individual columns using a Python code.

Please help. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please post the same data in the question rather than a link ?

Comment: @Sajan It has more than 21k entries and how do I post a spreadsheet in a question?

Comment: The first few rows would have been sufficient. Please check the answer below.

Comment: @Sajan Thanks! It is solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this -

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('AIOS_data.csv')
data['Mobile'] = data['Mobile'].str.extract(r'(Mobile[\d|\D]+Email)')
data['Mobile'] = data['Mobile'].str.replace('[Mobile:|Email:]', '').str.strip()
data['Email']  = data['Email'].str.extract(r'(Email:[\d|\D]+)')
data['Email']  = data['Email'].str.replace('Email:','').str.strip()
```

Comment: Please check edited code to remove trailing whitespaces. That check should have been there. Thanks @jezrael.

Comment: Please check edited answer to meet OP's requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with regex for filter values between values `Mobile` and `Email`, `\s*` means zero or some spaces and `(.*)` means extract any value between:

```
df[['Mobile','Email']] = df['Details'].str.extract('Mobile:\s*(.*)\s+Email:\s*(.*)')
```

If want also address:

```
cols = ['Address','Mobile','Email']
df[cols] = df['Details'].str.extract('Address:\s*(.*)\s*Mobile:\s*(.*)\s+Email:\s*(.*)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Without providing the full code, I guess you have to take three steps:

1. Read the csv-file into memory. Python has a handy module for that called `csv` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html))
2. Once you have done this, you can iterate over each row, and search in `detail` for the mobile number and email address. If `detail` is always written in the same way, you can just use the `str.find()` method ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)) for that.

E.g.

```py
detail = "Address: 108/81-B, METTU STREET, SE...KKAL TAMIL NADU 637409 Mobile: 9789617285 Email: Leens1794@gmail.com"
mobile_start = detail[detail.find("Mobile:")+8:]  # => '9789617285 Email: Leens1794@gmail.com'
mobile = mobile_start[:mobile_start.find(' ')]  # => '9789617285'
```

(You do the same for email)

3. You store the results (mobile and email) in a new column and export it to csv, again using the ``csv'' module.